# Faults/current leak in an ungrounded electric setup (connected to a grounded setup)

Tags: electrical, grounding, extension-cord

I'm troubleshooting the wiring from our neighbor's house. His electric setup is ungrounded. Our house, pending an "official" installation, gets its electricity via a ~30M cable (3x1.5mm2) from his house (only hot and neutral connected). Our house has a separate ground rod and connection linked to its more proper wiring.

The main issue: I notice leaking current on my laptop body. (Found e.g. at the outer metal of its USB-C power connector.) Multimeter shows neutral-to-earth variably at between 5-11V (readings taken at different times); corresponding to *hot@ground* minus *hot@neutral*. We haven't had this before, suggesting a change/fluke at the neighbor's side.

When I plug in a three-wire ("grounded") extension cable into a socket over at the neighbor's house, even with everything else turned off / disconnected, the ground connector shows significant voltage: Hot@ground at 100V, neutral@ground at 65V. This occurs even if I mask the ground connector at the plug, and only disappears when I disconnect the ground cable from the extension sockets. Tested with three different cables. These are probably just ghost readings (as in [this Q/A](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/149533/hot-to-ground-voltages-on-an-ungrounded-3-prong-outlet))?

I'm wondering if there's a neutral wire somewhere down the circuitry that's compromised, leading to a constant current on the neutral side. Other possible causes that explain the picture here? I'm struggling to find proper troubleshooting guides for ungrounded electric setups, given the modern day standard advice is "ground it".

Any insights on the situation would be much appreciated. All I really want to accomplish is get rid of the constant excess current on my ground. And ensure my neighbor's house doesn't burn down. From what I understand, it's not normal to have it over a couple of volts. (Creates glitches with my laptop's touchpad when I'm plugged in!)

--

P.S. This scenario is set in rural Indonesia, so please don't expect any standards compliance as the default state of affairs. To note, while I'm no professional, I've tinkered my fair bit, and given the sorts of bombs I've seen the average local electric clever-man come up with, going DIY is by far the sanest/safest way forward.

Comment: what's the voltage of the system there? 120vac? It sounds like you have possible bleed from neutral to a hot wire some where with the breaker not active and killing power. Would take time but most definitely worth it, check panel then out to outlets switch fans lights etc etc. Wish i was psychic and could tell you to go to the fan in main room or something  I've seen the issue occur within a fan motor near life end and it allowed voltage thru neutral so when grounded it was reading 65vac if i remember correctly

Comment: When are you due to get your own electric service?

Comment: We're actually due to move houses in the foreseeable future, a development project that's been postponed with the pandemic. For the time being, have to deal with this scenario and make the best (safest) I can out of it.

Comment: Indonesia has 220V AC. Most modern installations get a meter from the national electric company, capped at a particular wattage (in our neighbor's case a mere 450W), with three wires coming in: red (hot), blue (neutral), green-yellow (ground). Have no idea how the incoming ground is wired at the source. However in this case it's neither going via a ground rod or otherwise linked with the next house's wiring. We only pick up ground from our house's ground rod.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in. I will have to continue checking, yesterday I checked everything I could without a ladder, and cleaned up a bunch of potentially (eventually?!) hazardous build-ups of crap. Stuff happens here.... A couple of short-circuits caused by ants massively colonizing sockets come to mind. The other week the breaker in the company meter kept tripping, each time it tripped a line of tiny ants ran out from within it. Kept slapping the box and when they were all out, bordered it with a thick band of tiger balm (they hate it) a couple of times over. Problem solved. :D

Comment: Over 2.5v on a 120v system will cause problems with switching power supplies I am not sure if that value doubles for 240v systems. As far as current on the neutral the neutral is the return path so depending on your usage the voltage would vary. As far as your ground it may not be helping much if the original system is not grounded earth is a horrid conductor. What can cause voltages on the ground, harmonics. Unfortunately the power supply for your computer is probably the source and any other switching type power supplies. Normally used in fluorescent fixtures and led lighting.